# How can I remove unwated query parameters from url that are passed via Model?

Tags: c#, .net, url, .net-core

I created a simple login page in .net core C# with a model like so:

```
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }

        public string UserPassword { get; set; }
```

and i set it on my razor page like so:

```
<input type="email" id="email-user" class="form-control mb-4" asp-for="UserEmail" placeholder="E-mail">

<input type="password" id="password-user" class="form-control mb-4" asp-for="UserPassword" placeholder="Password">
```

after user clicks a button, he goes to next page but the url contains his email and password like so:

```
https://localhost:44306/User/Welcome?UserEmail=sampleemail%40gmail.com&UserPassword=dasdasdsa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using a GET request where you would want to use a POST request.

During a GET request, parameters can be sent throw the URL. 
In a POST request, you can send your parameters throw the body of the request.

Please consult [what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) and [this doc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to get more details on HTTP protocol.

Comment: hmm I am not using GET or POST it's just a simple website with Action Success (that returns a page with a simple hi message)

Comment: @HubertMijalski From your frontend, your form is sent throw the URL because your request is a GET. That's why you have those parameters in the URL.. Look at the <form> tag in your frontend, around your <input>s. Is it set to send throw GET or POST ?